# Nginx setting with multiple domain and https

Tags: nginx, https, multiple-domains

I want my server can have multiple domains and https.
So I had two server to listen 80 port and redirect to 443.

This is my setting

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example2.com;
    root /var/www/html/example2;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    return 301 https://example2.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/privkey.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    root /var/www/html/example2;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example2.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

But after I restarted the nginx service, it showed the failed message.
This error message is by "systemctl status nginx.service".

```
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 一 2018-05-07 20:55:52 CST; 44s ago
Process: 14870 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 13955 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 14874 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 13956 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

5月 07 20:55:52 my-server systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
5月 07 20:55:52 my-server nginx[14874]: nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for [::]:443 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:120
5月 07 20:55:52 my-server nginx[14874]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
5月 07 20:55:52 my-server systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
5月 07 20:55:52 ailab-server systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
5月 07 20:55:52 my-server systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
5月 07 20:55:52 my-server systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I was not sure the problem in my setting.
What wrong with my setting?
Thanks!

Comment: What "failed message"?

Comment: @Rob "Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server." by systemctl status nginx.service

Comment: Can you run this command and add the output to your question: `systemctl status nginx.service`

Comment: @Hackerman I has edited it.

Comment: `[emerg] a duplicate default server for [::]:443`...remove sites that you are not using anymore or the old default sites from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks! But I'm not sure what's the meaning  about [::]:443

Comment: It just happens tha you have a duplicate configuration on both of your `ssl` sites...this line `listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;` repeats in your config script...maybe renaming the second to `default_server2` should fix the issue.

Comment: @Hackerman Rename it did't work, but delete listen [::]:443 ssl default_server; was work.

Comment: Glad to help @CYL